# What is the class name for in this variable declaration?

Tags: objective-c

The Objective-C tutorial I'm following has has created a class called `Square` and a new instance of `Square`, the assigned it to a variable named `square` like so:

```
Square *square = [[Square alloc] init];
```

Now to my understanding this is what's happening.

This is creating an instance of the class `Square` and returning it; the returned instance is then being initialised, and set to the variable `square`:

```
*square = [[Square alloc] init];
```

I can't figure out why the first "`Square`" is needed in this or what it is doing.

Comment: because Objective-C is a statically typed language, you need to declare the type of your variables when allocating/initializing them. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: So I have to declare that my variable is of type Square class and then  assign an instance of the Square class to it?

Comment: Square *square means give me a variable named square of type Square (an instance of the Square class) just like NSString *square means give me a variable named square of type string. If you try to assign an object of the wrong type (anything that isn't an instance of the Square class) you'll get an error

Comment: @jckly yes, that is how Objective-C and as far as I know, all the C-based languages work. They are statically typed. Did you come from a PHP or Python background by chance?

Comment: Objective-C is often referred to as "duck typed".  The compiler itself behaves as in a true static-typed language, but if a pointer points to an object of a type different from its declared type, the behavior of the object corresponds to the actual object type, not the pointer's declared type.  Duck typing is not an excuse to stop using pointer types.

Comment: @HotLicks,  very good point! And there's also the id type, so it is sort of dynamic in that respect, but I do believe it is all just resolved with run-time message passing, is that correct?

Comment: @AlejandroLucena - It's really hard to describe Objective-C typing in 585 characters.  It is, after all, C under the covers, but the preprocessor generates a number of good/bad, expected/unexpected behaviors.

Comment: @AlejandroLucena I came from a basic ruby background so yeah just getting into C style languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Square *square = [[Square alloc] init]; 
  (1)     (2)       (3)    (4)    (5)
```

(1) is the Type of the object, so the instance created is of the type `Square`

(2) is the pointer to that instance.

(3)+(4) is the allocation method of this instance, meaning its alocating memory for this instance.

(5) is an initialization method which you can implement by yourself, for example, set the width of the square to 1.0

Comment: Very basic question, this answer does just about all you could ask to detail "what is going on" per the question.

Comment: You should alter your example to make `*` a separate item.  It is associated with "Square", not "square".

Answer (score 1):

From you initialization line:

```
Square *square = [[Square alloc] init];
```

The second `square` is the **name of the variable**, that's how you will refer to it later throughout the code. You can call this whatever you want. For example (now it's not so obvious that both `Square`s are redundant):

```
Square *a = [[Square alloc] init];
```

The first Square is the **type of variable** or **type of object**. The compiler will be able to help you by showing errors and warnings, and many of theses are based on the object type.

You could in fact declare it like this:

```
void *square = (void *)[[Square alloc] init];
```

This would mean that you're declaring your variable with a generic pointer type, but it's very likely that the compiler will give lots of warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `*square = [[Square alloc] init];` is wrong, without the type name "Square".  The `*` character is actually associated with the preceding type (`Square *`), not the following variable name.

The original statement could be written as:

```
Square *square;
square = [[Square alloc] init];
```

The first statement is the declaration of lower-case "square" as a variable of type `Square *`, where the `*` means "pointer to an entity of the preceding type".  (In fact, I prefer to write it like `Square* square = [[Square alloc] init];`, to make it clear that the `*` associates with "Square", but that's not the "usual convention".)

And it should be noted  that there is no real connection between the two names "Square" and "square".  They could be "Apples" and "oranges" and the logic of the program would be unchanged.  The first is the name of a class (by convention always beginning with a upper case letter) and the second is the name of a variable (by convention always beginning with a lower case letter).

Comment: `*square` says that the variable named `square` is a pointer. it associated with the variable and not with the type, but anyway, thats not matter since `Square* square` and `Square *square` are both good

Comment: @DimaGoltsman - `*square = [[Square alloc] init];` would assign the result of the `init` call to the location pointed to by `square`, not the variable `square` itself.  The `*` is a part of the type.

Comment: thats right, but i just thought he wrote it as part of the original line to ask why is that not enough or something